# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXqL7.png)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtjhc.png)

Comment: `var elmTasks = tasks && tasks.map(...`

Comment: please paste your code in the question description instead of an external link or image.

Answer (score 1):

You should have pasted your code for us to see, but I think the array variable is undefined that is the reason. You should check if it's contains a value before mapping.

By doing the following...

```
var elmTasks = tasks && tasks.map((task, index) => {
      return // do something with item... here
   })
```

Comment: Thank you for help me. My code is out of error